# How to prevent recursive KVO notifications?

Tags: cocoa, events, notifications, key-value-observing

I'm doing a UI for a university class in micro controllers. It's a user interface for a temperature controller thingie that controls the temperature in different rooms. For each room, I have an instance of a RoomViewController (an NSViewController subclass) which manages the a corresponding view which displays the current temp and the target temp which can be changed by the user.

My intention was to bind the value of the target temp display to a property in the RoomViewController using Cocoa bindings and then have another class listen to these properties to send these updates to the micro controller via serial. The problem is, changes can also come from the microcontroller which means that I have to set the property programmatically due to events from the micro controller. This would result in a property change notification leading to changing the value in the MCU which would lead to an event from the MCU which would lead to a property change and so on. It would turn into an infinite loop.

How can one prevent such feedback loops in KVO?

Answer (score 0):

Test (you said this was a university class!):

a) Does setting a property to its current value result in a KVO change notification?

b) On receiving an event from the MCU if you don't change your property if the new value will be the same does this break your cycle?

c) Think of another test you can do!

**Comment Response**

I'll assume you've tested (a) & (b) and found they don't do exactly what you require. So maybe what you're after is a single property with two setters? One setter triggers KVO the other does not...

Now you're talking about temperature so your property is presumably some numeric type. Is it a wrapped number, as in `NSNumber`, or a primitive number, as in `double`?

Let's assume the latter as the former is (a lot) more involved!

So:

1. You have a numeric, say `double`, property backed by an instance variable of the same type.
2. You've `@syntheize` the property have the compiler create a setter and a getter which alter/retrieve the value in that instance variable.
3. You're using KVO to pick up uses of the setter.
4. And you want to be able to set the property without triggering KVO.
5. And for a primitive numeric property all a setter needs to do is set the instance variable...

Problem solved. OK?

Comment: I don't want a property change event to be generated at all due to an event from the MCU. If the MCU tells me that the value has changed, I don't want the property change event to be sent since that would result in the application changing the value in the MCU that was just reported, something this is unnecessary. Only when the user manually edits the value should the change event occur. But perhaps KVO cannot be used this way.